# Best tool for monitoring the request and respone of any mobile app

Tags: php, android, mobile, windows-mobile, ads

My basic motive to see the all request of mobile app.

Suppose any app can have any number of banners displayed. In that case i want see from which servers app gets responnse and what is the format of request.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a http sniffer...

Do you want your phone to sniff and catch all these actions or do you want to make your desktop/laptop sniff and see what requests your phone does?

Comment: any laptop or mobile shoud able to sniff all the request/response urls.

Comment: I like wireshark: http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: Thanks ferdau, do you known how to use with a mobile which is attached with my laptop and whenever the app runs it should show all request. can you please let me know the process hot to do so. I am new to this android and app stuff....

Answer (score 0):

Why do you tag your question with "Windows Mobile", that is totally misleading. There is a MS tool for tcp capturing on Windows Mobile devices.

For ease of use I would setup a private WLAN network, add JANA or another proxy on the PC, configure android device to use the proxey for http and then look at the live log of the proxy.
Another approach is to install (or just download and run the portable version) WireShark. But you again need to setup a private WLAN so the android device connects to internet using a router. The router has to be connected via a hub with your PC. If you are using a switch, you have to define a mirror port to be able to see the traffic between the WLAN access point and the router.

How is your network setup to connect to the internet? Is it using a DSL connection or a direct connection using a router?

Next time be more specific.

regards

Josef

Comment: Thanks josef! it will really going to help me.  I want to known the process for both window and android because of which i have tagged with window and android.